# AWS SNS Java program to subscribe

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

- I am publishing a String message as message payload using SNS notification from Raspberry Pi using Python program and I want to pass that message payload to a Lambda function.
- I have configured the requirement in the SNS console on AWS i.e., I have created a topic and added the lambda function to its subscribers.
- Now, I want to get that message payload in the lambda function. But I can't find any method that can help me do that. For example, something like getMessage or something similar to that.
- So my questions are: Since I have configured the publishing and subscription on AWS, can I assume that the clients are connected and if I publish a message I should be getting that at the subscriber's end which is my lambda function here?
  Also, what's the technique in which I can get the message payload in my lambda function?
  I am adding the below as per cjwfuller's suggestion.
- Below I have written down the method for publishing in Python

`client_boto = boto3.client('sns', aws_access_key_id='@@@',
   aws_secret_access_key='@@@', region_name='us-west-2')`

`REGION = 'us-west-2'`

`TOPIC = 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:***:topic_name'`

`MSG = ntpath.basename(f_string)`

`SUBJECT_boto = 'File Name'`

`pub =client_boto.publish(TopicArn = TOPIC, Message = MSG,
   Subject=SUBJECT_boto)`

I am writing the subscribing code in Java.
   Since my lambda func is already subscribed to it on AWS console,
   should my Java program include the subscription again or is there a
   way to get the msg payload directly.

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you writing the function in?  JavaScript as an example:

```
exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log("value1 = " + event.key1);
    console.log("value2 = " + event.key2);
    // ...
}
```

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

It's useful testing the sort of stuff in the AWS Lambda console before writing all the code.

> Since I have configured the publishing and subscription on AWS, can I assume that the clients are connected

Clients aren't really "connected", they're simply subscribed to a topic.

> publish a message I should be getting that at the subscriber's end which is my lambda function here?

Sounds like you're doing the right sort of thing - posting example code will help us come up with more precise answers.

Comment: Below I have written down the method for publishing in Python
`client_boto = boto3.client('sns', aws_access_key_id='***', aws_secret_access_key='***', region_name='us-west-2')

REGION = 'us-west-2'
TOPIC  = 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:***:topic_name'
MSG = ntpath.basename(f_string)
SUBJECT_boto = 'File Name'

pub = client_boto.publish(TopicArn = TOPIC, Message = MSG, Subject=SUBJECT_boto)`
I am writing the subscribing code in Java. Since my lambda func is already subscribed to it on AWS console, should my Java program include the subscription again or is there a way to get the msg payload directly.

Comment: If you can see the subscription in the AWS console the subscription is definitely between the correct SNS topic and correct lambda function then no, you don't need to re-subscribe.  Also, which Java code are you subscribing in?  You probably shouldn't subscribe in the actual Lambda function code otherwise it will never get subscribed unless there's some manual invocation.

Comment: Oh so is the working like subscriber needs to subscribe first which is when it can receive the published message? If this is the case, then how does the use case specified by AWS work, in which it says that SNS can publish the message payload to Lambda function. If lambda is invoked by SNS then how can it be subscribed prior? 
Source: [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html]

Comment: Set up should be: 1) SNS topic + lambda function created 2) Lambda function subscribes to SNS topic (using console / CLI / CloudFormation.. one of the usual ways) 3) something publishes a SNS topic 4) lambda function gets invoked by a message being published to the topic.  "If lambda is invoked by SNS then how can it be subscribed prior?" Lambda is invoked with a message published to the topic.  The subscription will already have been set up

Comment: Great. That sounds exactly like what I have done so far. I have done step 1, 2 and 3. And step 4 is where my question lies, as in how can I get the message payload? [https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/aws-java-sdk-sns/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/sns ]
This is place where I have checked for all the classes of the SNS Java SDK. But unfortunately haven't found any method to get the message paylaod.

Answer (score 0):

On searching, I have found the class for SNSEvent which is, https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/SNSEvent.java

This Class contains all the methods related to and needed to get the message payload.

The Lambda function handler in Java goes something like this,
example;

```
public void handleRequest(SNSEvent input, Context context){
  String this_takes_message=input.getRecords().get(0).getSNS().getMessage();
}
```